# What do i do to print the menu options again?

Tags: java, menu, while-loop

```
     while(flag)
     {       
        System.out.println("Press 1 to Add Student details");
        System.out.println("Press 2 to Display Student details");
        System.out.println("Press 3 to Sort");
        System.out.println("Press 4 to Search");
        System.out.println("Press 5 to Exit");
        System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");

        while(!sc1.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter proper Integer input!");
            sc1.next();
        }

        choice = sc1.nextInt();
      //more code..
    }
```

In the above code I'm taking the input from the user. If the user enters anything other than an int, it is not accepted. Suppose, a string is given instead of a int, the message is printed and the menu is not displayed again. I want the menu to be displayed after the message. How do i do it?

Comment: Mark the answer as the suitable answer to close this post

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
while (flag) {
    System.out.println("Press 1 to Add Student details");
    System.out.println("Press 2 to Display Student details");
    System.out.println("Press 3 to Sort");
    System.out.println("Press 4 to Search");
    System.out.println("Press 5 to Exit");
    System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");

    if (sc1.hasNextInt()) {
        choice = sc1.nextInt();
        //more code here
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please enter proper Integer input!\n");
        sc1.next();
    }
}
```

i have added an extra `"\n"`for more readability. so that when the warning is printed the choices won't be printed in the very next line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the menu sysouts in inner loop as well. Like this:-

```
while(!sc1.hasNextInt())
{
    System.out.println("Please enter proper Integer input!");
    System.out.println("Press 1 to Add Student details");
    System.out.println("Press 2 to Display Student details");
    System.out.println("Press 3 to Sort");
    System.out.println("Press 4 to Search");
    System.out.println("Press 5 to Exit");
    System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
    sc1.next();
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way? I don't wanna repeat the code. `DRY principle`

Comment: Put the printing part in a method and make the method calls, wherever necessary! That's what methods are meant for, **Modularity**!